# MYSQL Update with a select

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update a value form another table value this is the my code

```
UPDATE 
ag_personal_information 
SET
ag_personal_information.ag_zone_id = 
  (SELECT ag_officer_service_information.ag_zone_id 
                  FROM ag_officer_service_information) 
WHERE
ag_officer_service_information.ag_zone_id <> ag_personal_information.ag_zone_id
```

Comment: So what is the question..?Is your update not workiking.?Are you gettng any errors.?

Comment: use `limit 1` in `SELECT ag_officer_service_information.ag_zone_id FROM ag_officer_service_information`, it may return more then one entry

Comment: What are the common columns in both tables? You can't join and update on the same column. Better yet [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17739974/edit) your question and provide sample data and desired outcome.

Comment: are you getting any problem.what is the question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UPDATE ag_personal_information AS A 
SET ag_personal_information.ag_zone_id = (
            SELECT ag_officer_service_information.ag_zone_id 
            FROM ag_officer_service_information AS B 
            WHERE A.ag_officer_service_information.ag_zone_id <> B.ag_personal_information.ag_zone_id)
```

Comment: It's not going to work (A and B are not schema names) and apart from that it makes no sense to update `ag_zone_id` with the same `ag_zone_id` that is used in the subquery.

Comment: sorry didnt notice the equal sign

Answer (score 0):

Put `=` in between `ag_officer_service_information.ag_zone_id` and `ag_personal_information.ag_zone_id`

```
 UPDATE ag_personal_information 
     SET ag_personal_information.ag_zone_id =
    (SELECT ag_officer_service_information.ag_zone_id FROM ag_officer_service_information) 
     WHERE ag_officer_service_information.ag_zone_id = ag_personal_information.ag_zone_id
```